# How to allocate memory on gpu for Conv2D op on raspberrypi3

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, matrix-multiplication, object-detection

I am trying to improve performance of object detection by implementing GEMM for Conv2D operation on gpu for Raspberry Pi3 and interfacing it with [GemmFunctors](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/gemm_functors.h#L109)

Though I am able to perform GEMM on gpu for Conv2D operation, it takes lot of time since I need to allocate memory on GPU,copy memory from cpu to GPU, perform GEMM and copy results back to CPU.

Is there any way I can tweak the [Allocator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc) in [Opkernel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc) to directly allocate memory on GPU for Conv2D operation, so that it avoids memcopy?

Also since previous and next operations of Conv2D will still run on CPU, how do I ensure the data transfer between CPU and GPU with minimum delay.